# Prevent triggering material multi select when setting a default value - Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've a material multiple select where I'm setting **conditionally** a default value inside the TS file. 
I also using the `onSelectionChange` to detect changes in the select.
The problem is that when I'm setting the default value the `onSelectionChange` being triggered, how can I prevent that from happening?

**HTML**

```
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareWithFunc" [(value)]="hidden" multiple>
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let value of values"
    (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChanged($event, value)"
    [value]="clause"
    >{{ value.name }}</mat-option
  >
</mat-select>
```

**TS**

```
 public onSelectionChanged(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, clause:any): void {
    if (event.source.selected) {}
  }

  public compareWithFunc(a, b) {
    return a.name === b.name;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the question is. Are you trying to conditionally set one of options' values? Or are you trying conditionally set the value of the box itself. The `[(values)]="hidden"` represents the value of the box. So as long as that value matches one of the option values, then it will be displayed as the default. Add more information or stackblitz example.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of the `mat-select` by using double binding `[(value)]="hidden"`.
So, if you change the `hidden` property from your `.ts` code, `onSelectionChange` will be triggered, since the value has changed.
I would recommend either to use the double binding strategy or the event capture one to prevent these issues.